# Get Refresh Token after callout failure

Tags: callout, oauth2, namedcredentials, refresh-token, authproviderpluginclass

- Named Credentials is setup for "ABC" and same details we are storing in ABC_Metadata__c.
- We are storing Refresh Token and Access Token in one record custom object Token__c.
- We have one Batch running every 15 minutes to get refreshed token and update in Token__c record.
- Sometimes this batch fails due to Error-500 or Error-401 etc.
  To connect with "ABC" again and have new Refresh Token & Access Token, we have to manually go and dummy update "Named Credentials - ABC"
- I want to avoid above manual step. From CATCH block of batch class I want to call AuthProvider class or reconnect again.

Any help or guidance will be really helpful and appreciated.

In Catch Block of Batch I tried:

```
Auth.OAuthRefreshResult refreshResult = providerClass.refresh(authProviderConfiguration,currentRefreshToken);
```

*Got error : 400-Bad Request {"ErrorCode" : "invalid_request", "Error" :"Invalid Refresh Token"}

EDIT 1:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<BHF_OLS_OAuthProvider__mdt> records) {
    try {
            //--------other code --------
        //callout to get new Refresh Token
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(oAuthProvider.Refresh_Token_URL__c);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setHeader('Content-Length', '71');
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(oAuthProvider.Key__c + ':' + oAuthProvider.Secret__c);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));
        request.setBody('refresh_token=' + tokenRecord.Refresh_Token__c + '&grant_type=refresh_token');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        System.debug('oauthtokenbatch'+request.getBody());


        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        response = http.send(request);
        String responseBody = response.getBody();
        
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            CalloutException calloutException = new CalloutException();
            calloutException.setMessage(String.valueOf(response.getStatusCode()) + '-' + response.getStatus() +
                ' ' + responseBody);
            throw calloutException;
        }
        
        //else store Token in custom object
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = (TokenResponse) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), TokenResponse.class);  //(custom wrapper)
        updateToken(tokenResponse);
        //--------other code --------
    
    }catch(Exception e){
    
        /********** HERE I want to make above same callout again to get refreshed token  *****/
        /********** OR Here I want to call "handleCallBack" method of my AuthProvider class *****/ 
                    
    }
```

}

EDIT 2:  My request is very similar to:
[Refresh Token using Salesforce Named Credentials and Auth Provider](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248596/refresh-token-using-salesforce-named-credentials-and-auth-provider?rq=1)

As @Jason Clark said in his answer, we already have implemented Scheduled job running every 15 min to ensure Refresh Token never expires.  But want to know implement something when it does expire / we run into errors in this scheduled batch !!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Instead of a _story_ with 1 line of code, including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Added batch code, hope that helps